# how to grep the results (plural) of another command

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a command whose output I want filtered by the results (plural; multiple lines) of another command. So far I've been sending the results of the first command to a file and filtering the second command with `grep -f`:

```
command1 > /tmp/output
command2 | grep -f /tmp/output
rm /tmp/output
```

I'd like to put that in a single command and not need the temp file.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Ideally, please provide (possibly anonymized) example output of both commands, along with the desired result. Also, please indicate which shell you are using - the answer will depend on the capabilities of the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell offers "process substitution", try

```
command2 | grep -f <(command1)
```

If not, you can also pass the list of regexps on the command line using command substitution:

```
command2 | grep -e "$(command1)"
```

That will have a lower limit on the maximum size of that list of regexps, and also means that it won't work if `command1`'s output contains NUL characters (many implementations of `grep` would choke on them with `-f` as well anyway).

Comment: Why "try"?  If the shell _does_ provide process substitutions, that would work. Just possibly note that the stuff read from `command1` will be treated as regular expressions and not plain strings.